Regarding upper numbering of ramification groups
In Serre's book "Local fields" he defines the function $\phi(u)=\int_{0}^{u}\frac{dt}{( G_0:G_t)}$ and defines the upper number of ramification groups as $G^v=G_{\phi^{-1}(v)}$ and somehow it magically turns out that the upper numbering is compatible with taking quotients.
I want to get some motivation regarding this. Like if I am someone who doesn't know about the upper numbering and who wants to find a numbering which is compatible with quotients, why would I think about the inverse of this function defined in terms of an integral.
Serre himself gives some explanation but it's not very clear to me. Any detailed answer regarding the motivation or even some historical note would be very useful.

I have in the past written a short note on higher ramification groups which tries to address this and some other questions. Let me summarize it below. Result numbers refer to the note linked, where I included full proofs. Some credit goes to Johannes Anschutz, whose lectures I followed when learning the subject.
Even if you do not a priori know that there is going to be a nice quotient-compatible numbering, it is still a natural question to ask how the higher ramification groups behave under taking quotients. Specifically, given a normal subgroup $H=Gal(L/M)$ of $G=Gal(L/K)$, what is the image of the ramification subgroup $G_i$ in the quotient $G/H$? Although not immediately obvious, it turns out to itself be a ramification group:
Proposition 1.8. We have $G_iH/H=(G/H)_j$ where
$$j=\frac{1}{e_{L/M}}\sum_{\tau\in H}\min(i_G(\tau),i+1)-1.$$
Here $i_G(\tau)$ is defined so that $\tau\in G_i$ iff $i_G(\tau)\geq i+1$ (this is the classical normalization, it would be a little cleaner without the $+1$, but oh well!), and $e_{L/M}$ is a ramification index. The proof a little computational but not hard, and comes down to understanding how $i_{G/H}$ and $i_G$ are related.
With this proposition at hand, for $\sigma\in G$ let us define
$$\varphi_{L/K}(\sigma)=\frac{1}{e_{L/K}}\sum_{\sigma\in G}\min(i_G(\tau),i+1)-1$$
so that the proposition gives $G_iH/H=(G/H)_{\varphi_{L/M}(i)}$. As should not be surprising from this relation, these functions behave well in towers:
Lemma 2.1. We have $\varphi_{L/K}=\varphi_{M/K}\circ\varphi_{L/M}$.
With this result in mind, it is easy to see that this may give us a more convenient numbering. Indeed, if we define the numbering so that $G_i=G^{\varphi_{L/K}(i)}$ and analogously for $G/H$, we get
$$G^{\varphi_{L/K}(i)}H/H=G_iH/H=(G/H)_{\varphi_{L/M}(i)}=(G/H)^{\varphi_{M/K}(\varphi_{L/M}(i))}=(G/H)^{\varphi_{L/K}(i)}.$$
Thus setting $G^j=G_{\varphi_{L/K}^{-1}(j)}$ gives a numbering compatible with quotients (Theorem 2.3).
Now the only sticking point is, my $\varphi$ is different from your $\phi$! But it turns out that they are, after all, the same value. This comes out of the proof of Lemma 2.1 - $\varphi$ has a very easy derivative, as really you are just counting how many terms in that sum are increasing, and the answer is precisely $|G_i|$. The integral formula then merely comes down to integrating this derivative, equal to $\frac{|G_i|}{e_{L/K}}=\frac{|G_i|}{|G_0|}=\frac{1}{[G_0:G_i]}$.

Ah I see. This looks like a really clean way of introducing the function than defining it a priory and then checking it satisfies the properties. Thanks a lot for your detailed answer

I have a way of making the Hasse-Herbrand transition function the primary object, too, and it proves the functoriality without talking about Galois groups. It’s in a paper in J.Numb.Th. from 2013.
